# Started playing with Coffeescript - couple of basic questions

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

**1 - Method Chaining**

I really love the way you can call functions without polluting your code with brackets, but the following inconsistency really bothers me;

```
$(this).attr("id").data "foo"
```

Method chaining like this pretty much requires me to use brackets up till the last method in the chain, this seems pretty inconsistent and makes my OCD sense tingle like crazy.. am I miss-understanding something here? Is there a more consistent but clean approach (ie. aside from reverting to using brackets everywhere).

**2 - Compiler config?**

I use coffee --watch to have it automatically compile the files, however the --help shows very few arguments I can give to change it's behaviour. For one thing I'd like to change the tab size of the resulting javascript. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Removing parens from intermediate expressions is non-trivial; what is `attr "id".data "foo"`? Is it `attr("id").data("foo")`, or `attr("id".data("foo"))`? Doing this in a general way is a lot harder than might be preferable.

Comment: It could also be `attr("id".data)("foo")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Chaining**

No, it really isn't much cleaner than javascript, as far as syntax goes. And [lots of people](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/search?q=chaining) are complaining about it. I think you just have to bite the bullet and accept that you have to know javascript to use coffeescript, and that not all the warts of javascript are solved (yet, anyway). Personally I prefer the d3 or jQuery solution of judicious indenting:

```
$(this)
  .attr('id')
  .data('foo')
```

**2. Compiler config**

There aren't any configs apart from the '--bare' options that I'm aware of. Buts its a compiler, not a formatter. You can send your compiled code all through [JS Beautfy](https://github.com/carlo/js-beautify-node) (or [Uglify](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) for that matter). If you plan on doing this, I highly recommend [using a Cakefile](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html). Check out [this link](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/%5BExtensibility%5D-Hooking-into-the-Command-Line-Compiler) for how you can work with the coffee compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the info. You pretty much confirmed my fears. Hopefully it will develop into a more robust language soon, or a fork will appear that aims to do things right from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you need the parentheses if you want to do chaining. I wish it wasn't so, but it is
2. Not that I know of. What you see in `--help` is what you get

But CoffeeScript is open source, so you can always hack around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to your OCD consistency tingling, is to always include parenthesis for method/function arguments. Chaining isn't the only situation where you need to include them. My personal preference would be for the optional omission of parenthesis to be removed from the language but that's probably too extreme for most CoffeeScript users. Instead, I'm choosing to ignore this one "feature" of CS and encouraging my collaborators to do the same. I make the case for it [here](http://maccherone.com/larry/2012/02/02/the-coffeescript-emperor-has-no-clothes/).